# Does THREE have a utility for loading canvases in an async manner?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with some pictures and I would like to load it onto a texture much like an image with ImageUtils. As you know canvas has no 'onfinished' rendering callback so I am at the mercy of THREE here. I have come across [this](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/LoadingManager) but this seems to be tightly coupled with AJAX.

Comment: Not an expert in THREE, but how are you drawing your pictures on the first canvas? You should rely on the onload of each img tags, then everything else can be done directly, synchronously

Comment: I use onload to assign a base64 img string to a property in a model. Then I read the model and render the base64 string onto the cavas. I need THREE to detect when the image is fully loaded and update my textures accordingly.

Comment: I think that a code snippet would help us to help you.

Comment: Why not use <img> instead of <canvas>? http://jsfiddle.net/zc4c10yh/

Answer (score 0):

You can read the image from the canvas as a data url:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

After you execute drawImage on the canvas, the image data is already going to be inside there.

These data urls then can be used as textures in Three.js.

```
 var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(dataURL);
```

**Update**

You could also try this for debugging:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(dataURL, undefined, function(texture){
    // Handler for onLoad, this returns the img
    console.log(texture);
 },
 function(event){
    // Handler for onError, it returns the error event
    console.log(event);
 });
```

Comment: Seems like a perfectly valid suggestion but I am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Comment: Which JS file? Is it from inside Three.js? What's the dataURL generated?

Comment: CanvasRenderer.js:841 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Comment: Looks like texture.image is undefined. Did you try opening the dataURL in a browser? It should be able to open it correctly. Also added some help for debugging in my answer.